# Create object/array from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, meteor, split

I can't figure out how to get the output that I want.

I have this code:

```
var rawLines = rawText.split('\n');

var object = {};
rawLines.forEach(function(rawLines) {
    var objectEntry = rawLines.split(' ');
    object[objectEntry[0]] = objectEntry[1];
});
```

Which gives this output:

```
Object { 85.164.152.30="-", 178.232.38.87="-", 193.212.51.164="-", more...}
```

I want the output to be

```
Object { host="85.164.152.30", host="178.232.38.87", host="193.212.51.164", more...}
```

I've tried to change the line

```
object[objectEntry[0]] = objectEntry[1];
```

to

```
object['host'] = objectEntry[0];
```

But that outputs only:

```
Object { host=""}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple properties with the same name inside an object. Meaning, it's impossible to produce the output you want.

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense. I'll have to use Array then, I guess?

Comment: Yes, you could have `["85.164.152.30", "178.232.38.87", ...]`

Comment: Cheers! Already working on switching to array :)

Comment: Have you tried creating a collection insert for each new host

Comment: Hey @rwatts! :D No - I have not tried a collection insert, I'd love to see an example of it if you have it!